# ReactJS date picker issue with year only selection in Windows XP

Tags: reactjs, windows-xp, react-datetime

We developed ReactJS app and used ***react-datetime*** for selecting date and Year.

When selecting YEAR in client machine(Windows XP-Firefox 52.09), value(year) decreased by **1**. Same thing happen if we use ***new Date(2018-01-01)*** converted to ***"2017-01-01"***

**Note**

> My Client using Firefox 52.09 on Windows XP (We know windows xp service ended but
>   client have few + features in XP)

**Sample Code**

```
var date = new Date();
React.render(
    <Datetime value = {new Date('2011-01-01')} dateFormat="YYYY"/>,
    document.body
);
```

Please find Example at https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gdGaNp

Attached screen shot also [image]

Comment: recreate it on stackblitz, codepen doesn't work on older xp ;)

Comment: hello @xadm, please find link here https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-azaqag?file=Hello.js

Comment: `2011` in FF ESR 45.9.0

Comment: 2010 in ESR FF 52.9.0  Please find image here https://ibb.co/d1aLPe

Comment: don't take year alone - check full value in dev-react component props - it can be difference in hours - TZ-related - for `console.log(new Date('2011-01-01'))` I have `Date 2011-01-01T00:00:00.000Z` - difference in minus would be 2010-12-31...

Comment: Thanks @xadm . Got the issue. Our client using specifying US timezone systems. So i changed code with adding of UTC to selected date

Comment: XP & FF not guilty ;)

Answer (score 0):

**Found the solution**

When adding UTC to selected date, it's working

```
<Datetime value={new Moment.utc(new Date('2011-01-01'))}/>
```

**With UTC and non-UTC Sample** https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-e8fa6w?file=Hello.js